# Print the Labels ONLY in Printer and not the Form in C#

Tags: c#, printing, label

I developed an application in C# and i want to print in the printer the labels ONLY in my form but instead its printing the whole form. 
     My four Labels are `lblName, lblAge, lblAdd, lblEmail`. I want ONLY these labels to print and not the form. Can someone help me pls. Thanks!

Anyway this is my code to print when I click the button.

```
private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    PaperSize pp = new PaperSize("MyReport", 718, 359);
    printForm1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = pp;
    printForm1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0);
  //printForm1.PrintAction = System.Drawing.Printing.PrintAction.PrintToPreview;
    printForm1.Print(this, PrintForm.PrintOption.CompatibleModeClientAreaOnly);

}
```

Comment: I just put here the code to my button for printing but I have other codes like for calling the datas from the database. Its like I will get the data from the database then print to an ID Card afterwards.

Comment: I got the Answer! It printed.. 
Now my only problem is why is it blurred? Or pixelated rather? :(
Its not like in MS Word Document where it prints clean. I know about crystal report but I cant use it for a certain reason. Pls help me guys.. :(

Answer (score 1):

You may find what you are looking for here where you put contents into a Panel control and print that: [Print Panel in Windows Form C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605840/print-panel-in-windows-form-c-sharp)

This was my Quick and Dirty approach. This would work if you have everything on a white form and just want to show labels, print and closed form. The above might be better though!

```
private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    PaperSize pp = new PaperSize("MyReport", 718, 359);
    printForm1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = pp;
    printForm1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0);

    // Show the labels...
    lblAge.Visible = true;
    lblAdd.Visible = true;
    lblName.Visible = true;
    lblEmail.Visible = true;

    // ...Print them visible...
    printForm1.Print(this, PrintForm.PrintOption.CompatibleModeClientAreaOnly);

    // ...Then hide again
    lblAge.Visible = false;
    lblAdd.Visible = false;
    lblName.Visible = false;
    lblEmail.Visible = false;

}
```

Comment: that is best, but otherwise you should use some reporting module, that print with specific information.

Comment: No the labels are actually visible. But the thing is Its like i want the form to be transparent. I will print this to an ID card, thats the reason why. :)

Comment: Expanded answer to include link to similar thing you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Or should I use textBoxes rather than labels?

Comment: That shouldn't matter, once you get print out how you want they are just cosmetic differences as you are not taking input (text boxes) but may want border around them. Depends on what you want it to look like on card etc.

Comment: I got the Answer! It printed.. 
Now my only problem is why is it blurred? Or pixelated rather? :(
Its not like in MS Word Document where it prints clean. I know about crystal report but I cant use it for a certain reason. Pls help me guys.. :(

Comment: This looks like it will answer your question but doesn't sound like there is much of a resolution other than don't print forms but talk directly to printer etc: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726502/printing-windows-form

Comment: @Belogix It gives me an error: An error has occurred - please retry your request.